# NetNamedPipeBinding: parameter in pipe method is empty

Tags: c#, wcf, servicehost, netnamedpipebinding

I have a ServiceHost listening on a NetNamedPipeBinding endpoint.  I have a service contract class with a single method which is being called by the client and handled by the server.  The method (We'll call it PipeRequest()) has a Request parameter.  On the client side I populate this object but it's empty by the time it gets sent over to the server.  Any ideas why this would be the case?

```
_Host = new ServiceHost(typeof(PipeService), new Uri(ServiceRequestRouter.URI));
_Host.AddServiceEndpoint(
    typeof(IPipeService),
    new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
    _PipeName
);
_Host.Open();

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.example.com/PipeCommunication")]
interface IPipeService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void PipeRequest(ServiceRequestBase request);
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(DerivedServiceRequest))]
[KnownType(typeof(SomeEnumType))]
public abstract class ServiceRequestBase
{
    ...

    public void Dispatch(string pPipeName = ServiceRequestRouter.DefaultPipeName)
    {
        EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress(_address_));
        IPipeService proxy = ChannelFactory<IPipeService>.CreateChannel(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), epa);
        proxy.PipeRequest(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that call the PipeRequest please.

Comment: Perhaps the service contract isn't properly handling inheritance.  Or perhaps I'm not properly implementing inheritance.  Can anyone confirm either of these hypotheses?

Comment: The `KnownType` attribute is a correct way to implement inheritance; if you'd set that up incorrectly you'd get an exception. When you say the parameter is 'empty' - is it null, or does it have properties which don't have the values you expect?

Comment: Strings are simply "" empty.  Enums are 0 even though the only possibilities are { EnumVal1 = 1, EnumVal2 = 2 }.  Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had to specify (as part of the data contract) any derived classes from ServiceRequestBase class.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(CitrixInfoServiceRequest))]   // added this line
[KnownType(typeof(RegStateServiceRequest))] // added this line
public abstract class ServiceRequestBase
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It look like it has to do with `proxy.PipeRequest(this);`
You need to pass in a class that inherits ServiceRequestBase, if you class does inherit the ServiceRequestBase then it might not be serializable.

Comment: The Dispatch() method is actually in the ServiceRequestBase class.  I'll correct that in my post.